# Why doesn't this JavaScript run in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-6

It certainly runs on IE6.

Why doesn't this JavaScript run in Mozilla Firefox?

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
function MyClass()
{
    this.OpenWindow = function()
    {
        var r = window.open ('', 'mywindow', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100');
        r.moveTo(0,0);
        r.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }

}
</SCRIPT>
<body onload="javascript: new MyClass().OpenWindow()">
<H1>JavaScript Popup Example 3</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future make sure you put a version number for Firefox. You can find it in Help --> About Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" protocol prefix in your onload attribute.  The content of the on* attributes expect a script value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It runs just fine in my FF. For me the popup blocker is catching it.

Did you notice that little bar just below the tabs selection

[alt text http://support.mozilla.com/img/wiki_up/86c0e1094489ddd5611008de57d0afed-1249166734-294-5.png](http://support.mozilla.com/img/wiki_up/86c0e1094489ddd5611008de57d0afed-1249166734-294-5.png)

Check here for more information + images: [FF Pop-up blocker](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Pop-up%20blocker)

Answer (score 0):

[image: pop up blocker settings]

Just go to the FF menu -> option -> content -> block-pop-up-windows

Uncheck the option, click <kbd>OK</kbd> and try reload the page. It should now work fine for you. Also, don't forget to tick the check box again if you worry about security.